# Pytorch tensor - randomly replace values that meet condition

Tags: python, replace, pytorch, tensor

I have a Pytorch tensor `mask` of dimensions,

```
torch.Size([8, 24, 24])
```

with unique values,

```
> torch.unique(mask, return_counts=True)
(tensor([0, 1, 2]), tensor([2093, 1054, 1461]))
```

I wish to randomly replace the number of 2s to 0s, such that the unique values and counts in the tensor become,

```
> torch.unique(mask, return_counts=True)
(tensor([0, 1, 2]), tensor([2500, 1054, 1054]))
```

I have tried using `torch.where` to no success. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the possible solutions is through flattening via `view` and `numpy.random.choice`:

```
from numpy.random import choice

idx = torch.where(mask.view(-1) == 2)[0]  # get all indicies of 2 in flat tensor

num_to_change = 2500 - 2093 # as follows from example above

idx_to_change = choice(idx, size=num_to_change, replace=False)

mask.view(-1)[idx_to_change] = 0
```